# Dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I was just dropping a column from dataframe. it was dropped. after calling show method, it seems like column is not dropped in dataframe.

Code:

```
df.drop('Salary').show()

+-----+
| Name|
+-----+
| Arun|
|  Joe|
|Jerry|
+-----+

df.show()
+-----+------+
| Name|Salary|
+-----+------+
| Arun|  5000|
|  Joe|  6300|
|Jerry|  9600|
+-----+------+
```

I am using spark 2.4.4 version. could you please tell why its not dropped? And I thought that its like a  dropping column form table in oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

The `drop` method returns a new DataFrame. The original `df` is not changed by this transformation, so calling `df.show()` a second time will return the original data with your `Salary` column.

Comment: It won't change the DataFrame, it will create a new one, keeping `df` unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the dataframe after dropping.

```
df2 = df.drop('Salary')
df2.show()
```